# How to INSERT new record using column field default with FK

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to `INSERT` a new record into a table (`employee`) where a few of the columns are `FK`'s that are linked to other tables (`license` and `car`) `PK`'s. The table(1) has a default set for these columns that reflect the same value listed in the table(2+3) `PK`.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO employee (Emp_ID, Lic_ID, Car_ID) Values ('1234', ' ', ' ')

Tables:

table(1) = employee
      PK = Emp_ID
      FK = Lic_ID, default = 1
      FK = Car_ID, default = 1

table(2) = license
      PK = Lic_ID
 records = 1 through 8

table(3) = car
      PK = Car_ID
 records = 1 through 6
```

The problem is, whenever I try to run that insert statement, I get:

`Error: 1452 "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"`

I don't want to have to enter a value into the `Lic_ID` or `Car_ID` fields when I create the employee because they may not have either one of those assigned to them. What I want is for the table to use the default value of '1', what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use default values, then remove field names from the INSERT statement -

```
INSERT INTO employee (Emp_ID) Values ('1234');
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: INSERT INTO employee (Emp_ID, Lic_ID, Car_ID) Values ('1234', NULL,NULL) , This also can use default values,Bug @Devart method is best!